# How to manage different projects in git

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am currently making different repository for different client in git.
My Scenario is, currently we are having 28 schools as client for school ERP. Some changes are applicable for all 28 clients and some changes are customized for individual client.
-->Suppose there is 'Change A', which need to be reflected to all 28 git projects in gitlab at once, when I will push change.
-->And if there is 'Change B', let us say, then I should be able to update those changes in specified clients say 5 clients

Currently we are using gitlab

Comment: Consider using a dependency manager where each dependency is contained within a repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think, you need to maintain 28 repository for this use case. You may design your project structure like this, and reduce the repository number to 1.

- Put all the common files in one branch, Lets say `master`
- Maintain different branch for different clients.

Any changes in branch `master` can be pulled for clients

```
git pull origin master
```